# simple python code wont convert string to float

Tags: python-3.x, scripting-language

I trying to write code to show how high a ball would go up from the calculation
however no matter how I type it, it keeps saying that it "`cannot convert string to float`" on the height varible

```
time = input("How long did the ball go up? in seconds\n")
time = float(time)

velocity = input("What was the initial velocity?\n")
velocity = float(velocity)

height = ("What was the initial height?\n")
height = float(height)

answer = (time ** 2 * -16) + (velocity * time) + height

print(answer)
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'What was the initial height?\n'

why does the code not want to convert?

Comment: You missed `input` to read `height`.

Comment: typo: you want `height = input("What was the initial height?\n")`

Comment: damn didn't see that, thank you for helping me the code works now

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because time is a `string`. You can't change the datatype, but you can cast it. What you should do instead is:

```
time = input("How long did the ball go up? in seconds\n")

velocity = input("What was the initial velocity?\n")

height = input("What was the initial height?\n")

answer = (float(time) ** 2 * -16) + (float(velocity) * float(time)) + float(height)

print(answer)
```